# rotating android.graphics.picture object on SurfaceView without a bitmap conversion?

Tags: android, bitmap, rotation

Can't get android.graphics.***picture*** objects to *rotate*, but translates are OK. **No camera involved** in the following code.

For making dynamic sprites, *recording* drawing primitives into an android.graphics.***picture*** object for later use seems consistently more efficient than doing individual primitive draws during onDraw. And a Picture object is very similar to a bitmap, (if not the same?) and can be saved and restored to / from a bitmap.

However, just to be able to *rotate* these Pictures, I'd like to avoid having to save them as Bitmaps after recording() them.  That is, just use the Picture objects like bitmaps, which **the canvas api seems to imply is possible**. Perhaps the Picture API is less sophisticated, but more likely I'm just doing this wrong.

The canvas API for Bitmaps versus Pictures are not parallel, e.g. there is a:

```
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap_Sprite, matrix, null); // Draw sprite with matrix, no Paint
```

And there is a:

```
    canvas.drawPicture(picture_Sprite, destination_rectangle); Draw sprite into rect.
```

But there ***isn't*** a:

```
    canvas.drawPicture(picture_Sprite, matrix ...)
```

- **Details**:

Imagine both bitmap_Sprite and picture_Sprite are a "compass arrow" indicating where it's pointing during rotation.

In the onDraw() call, using the bitmap version, this works:

```
     matrix = new matrix();
     matrix.setRotate(angle);  // angle is ++ during onDraw(canvas)

     // Draw arrow, matrix rotates it as expected:
     canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap_Sprite, matrix, null); // null = no Paint obj
```

But attempting the same thing using the picture object, the only way I could figure this out was to rotate the the destination_rectangle (containing the arrow) like this:

```
     //destination_rectangle sized correctly to wrap previously recorded picture obj.
     matrix2 = new matrix();
     matrix2.setRotate(angle);  // angle is ++ during onDraw(canvas)

     matrix2.mapRect(destination_rectangle); // apply rotation
     canvas.drawPicture(picture_Sprite, destination_rectangle);
```

But all this does is *pivot* the rectangle around a location, it doesn't *rotate* the rectangle (and the arrow) itself.

- **Questions:**

  - Is using the destination rect. the wrong way to do this?
  - Is rotation even possible using a Picture object?

Certainly, if I can't get Picture objects to rotate, then I could just use previously created bitmaps / mipmaps directly.  So then

- Generally, assuming it is possible to use Picture objects the same way as Bitmaps, am I really saving overhead using Pictures which are dynamically created once versus dynamically creating them, saving them as bitmaps, and reloading the bitmaps to do the matrix stuff?(!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use Canvas.concat, you will probably want save/restore as well

Comment: Super! +5 I just love it when I post a ginormous question - and get a one line answer that is spot on.  Would have never guessed .concat ... save/restore is a bit weird as canvas.drawPicture does its own save/restore, but at least the Picture object rotates now as expected!  Any thoughts on the overhead issues?

Comment: oops, forgot about Canvas.setMatrix it can be faster as it completly replaces the matrix

Comment: ok cool, got this working thanks to your assistance! Canvas.setMatrix does work, but is discouraged in the docs (but it doesn't say why).  Also, compared w/Canvas.concat, setMatrix didn't seem to affect the framerate if at all, afaict. (However, I'm running only at 20-25 fps, which is good enough for this particular application.)  Save and restore didn't matter here either, probably because of my first comment above. The order of calls, not just because of matrix math, is, of course significant.